# Spring Data REST - Sort is always null in Pageable parameter in rest controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am using Spring Data REST with Spring Boot (1.5.17) and I have the following controller in my code.

```
@RestController
public class StudentController {

    @RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "students/{id}/notifications")
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<?> getStudentNotifications(@PathVariable Long id, PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler, Pageable page) {

            Student student = studentRepo.findOne(id);

            Page<Notification> notifications = notificationHandler.getUnreadNotifications(student.getId(),page);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(pagedResourcesAssembler.toResource(notifications, resourceAssembler), HttpStatus.OK);


    }
}
```

The controller works correctly except I cannot use the sort parameter like `students/1/notifications?sort=createdDate,DESC`. It always sorts by created date in ascending order.

I printed the Pageable parameter to console `[number: 0, size 20, sort: null]` and it shows that the sort attribute is always null.

So what am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

**MVC configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class SpringMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("repositoryExporterHandlerAdapter")
    RequestMappingHandlerAdapter repositoryExporterHandlerAdapter;

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(
            List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> customArgumentResolvers = repositoryExporterHandlerAdapter.getCustomArgumentResolvers();
        argumentResolvers.addAll(customArgumentResolvers);
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

    }

}
```

Comment: add queryParams for your sort

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: What are your queryParams

Comment: `students/1/notifications?sort=createdDate,DESC`

Comment: Did you include `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` into configuration in order to use Pageable argument in REST controller methods?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I have updated my question. Is that what youre talking about?

Answer (score 1):

> The controller works correctly except I cannot use the sort parameter
>   like students/1/notifications?createdDate,DESC. It always sorts by
>   created date in ascending order.

if you are trying to pass the sort in

> students/1/notifications?createdDate,DESC

it will not works because Pageable has sort params and you need to call like below.

> students/1/notifications??sort=createdDate,DESC

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the question. I am using the sort parameter as you mentioned but its not working

Comment: Okay, can you also post the entity object on which you want to apply sort?

Comment: *Sorry I made a mistake in the question*. Ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

Add following to `addArgumentResolvers` method

```java
argumentResolvers.add(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but I found that there was no problem with the controller. Actually the createdDate filed is a json ignored field thats why the sort was not working